# Как использовать директиву из стороннего компонента ES5?

Tags: vue.js

Есть [библиотека](https://github.com/vuejs-tips/vue-the-mask) для vuejs. Нужно из нее использовать директиву. Как это сделать в рамках ES5? Проект без сборщика.

Такой вариант не работает.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#forms',
    directives: {mask}
})
```

Библиотека подключена до vuejs

Comment: А импорт под названием mask? Ошибки консоли есть? Вот что они предлагают перед инициализацией `import {mask} from 'vue-the-mask'`

Comment: @RuslanSemenov import - это ES6. Естественно браузер выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо обзявлять компонент как директиву.
Просто используй директиву и все заработает само собой:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
})

<input type="tel" v-mask="'##/##/####'" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6Lepbzv2/